# Membership Providers

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, membership-provider, asp.net-web-api

My first question is: Is there difference betwen apsnetmembershipprovider and simplemembershipprovider. I know that aspnetmembershipprovider is disgusting, because it always create temporary tables. so I'm wondering is SimpleMembershipProvider uses AspNetMembership sql queries or anather.

And My Second Question is what membership provider use for Web Api project, where client app will be mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

this description can be helpful:

> The WebSecurity helper class is the recommended way to manage user (membership) accounts, passwords, and other membership tasks. The SimpleMembershipProvider class can manage membership tasks; however, it is not recommended because WebSecurity provides a simpler way to implement membership. **The SimpleMembershipProvider class is intended for developers who require more precise control over the membership process**.

You can read more here, section "Remarks": [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider(v=vs.111).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

If you don't like the way provider does the tables in the database, you could implement your own provider or use the Entity Framework Membership Provider (if you use EF): http://efmembership.codeplex.com/

Comment: Ok, but I care about what SimpleMembership uses for Web Pages, but my project is Web Api. Or there is no difference betwen using it in Web Pages or in Web Api.

Comment: if i correctly understand this topic it is bad use SimpleMembership in Web Api, because it was created only for web pages, but I tried to use this with Web Api + Basic Authenfication and it`s work. Or it is better to implement my own membership provider.